# A faster function to lower the resolution of a raster R

Tags: r, aggregate, raster, r-raster

I am using the raster package to lower the resolution of big rasters, using the function aggregate like this

```
require(raster)    
x <- matrix(rpois(1000000, 2),1000)

a <-raster(x)
plot(a)

agg.fun <- function(x,...) 
    if(sum(x)==0){
        return(NA)
    } else {
        which.max(table(x))
    }

a1<-aggregate(a,fact=10,fun=agg.fun)
plot(a1)
```

the raster images I have to aggregate are much bigger 34000x34000 so I would like to know if there is a faster way to implement the agg.fun function.

Comment: Please note that `which.max(table(x))` returns the index of the value having max repetition, not the value. Most likey in your case indexes will coincide with values but to be sure to have the value you should use `as.numeric(names(which.max(table(x))))`...

Comment: As far as performance is concerned... well I guess you should resort to some Rcpp piece of code to gain something...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `gdalUtils::gdalwarp` for this. For me, it's less efficient than @JosephWood's `fasterAgg.Fun` for rasters with 1,000,000 cells, but for Joseph's larger example it's much faster. It requires that the raster exists on disk, so factor writing time into the below if your raster is in memory.

Below, I've used the modification of `fasterAgg.Fun` that returns the most frequent *value*, rather than its index in the block.

```
library(raster)
x <- matrix(rpois(10^8, 2), 10000)
a <- raster(x)

fasterAgg.Fun <- function(x,...) {
    myRle.Alt <- function (x1) {
        n1 <- length(x1)
        y1 <- x1[-1L] != x1[-n1]
        i <- c(which(y1), n1)
        x1[i][which.max(diff(c(0L, i)))]
    }

    if (sum(x)==0) {
        return(NA)
    } else {
        myRle.Alt(sort(x, method="quick"))
    }
}
system.time(a2 <- aggregate(a, fact=10, fun=fasterAgg.Fun))

##   user  system elapsed 
##  67.42    8.82   76.38

library(gdalUtils)
writeRaster(a, f <- tempfile(fileext='.tif'), datatype='INT1U')
system.time(a3 <- gdalwarp(f, f2 <- tempfile(fileext='.tif'), r='mode', 
                           multi=TRUE, tr=res(a)*10, output_Raster=TRUE))

##   user  system elapsed 
##   0.00    0.00    2.93
```

Note that there is a slight difference in the definition of the mode when there are ties: `gdalwarp` selects the highest value, while the functions passed to `aggregate` above (via `which.max`'s behaviour) select the lowest (e.g., see `which.max(table(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4)))`).

Also, storing the raster data as integer is important (when applicable). If the data are stored as float (the `writeRaster` default), for example, the `gdalwarp` operation above takes ~14 sec on my system. See `?dataType` for available types.

Comment: For R users without GDAL installed on their computer, `gdalUtilities::gdalwarp()` (from my [**gdalUtilities**](https://github.com/JoshOBrien/gdalUtilities) package) is another option. It carries out the same computation as the `gdalUtils::gdalwarp()` call above, faster and without the requiring an external GDAL install. The one small difference is that it does not accept an `output_Raster=` argument.

Comment: Wow, that's fantastic @JoshO'Brien - I think `gdalUtilities` will be very useful for me.

Comment: Thanks! I developed it to support a geospatial tool used by agency biologists across the western US -- an application in which portability and ease of installation were key. It's already turned out to be useful to me several other times, so I thought it might be worth leaving a note here. Now I'm glad that I did.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
fasterAgg.Fun <- function(x,...) {
    myRle.Alt <- function (x1) {
        n1 <- length(x1)
        y1 <- x1[-1L] != x1[-n1]
        i <- c(which(y1), n1)
        which.max(diff(c(0L, i)))
    }

    if (sum(x)==0) {
        return(NA)
    } else {
        myRle.Alt(sort(x, method="quick"))
    }
}

library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(FasterAgg=aggregate(a, fact=10, fun=fasterAgg.Fun),
            AggFun=aggregate(a, fact=10, fun=agg.fun),
            replications=10,
            columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed", "relative"),
            order = "relative")
       test replications elapsed relative
1 FasterAgg           10  12.896    1.000
2    AggFun           10  30.454    2.362
```

For a larger test object, we have:

```
x <- matrix(rpois(10^8,2),10000)
a <- raster(x)
system.time(a2 <- aggregate(a, fact=10, fun=fasterAgg.Fun))
   user  system elapsed 
111.271  22.225 133.943  

system.time(a1 <- aggregate(a, fact=10, fun=agg.fun))
   user  system elapsed 
282.170  24.327 308.112
```

If you want the actual values as @digEmAll says in the comments above, simply change the return value in `myRle.Alt` from `which.max(diff(c(0L, i)))` to `x1[i][which.max(diff(c(0L, i)))]`.

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun I created also an Rcpp function (not much faster than @JosephWood) :

```
########### original function 
#(modified to return most frequent value instead of index)
agg.fun <- function(x,...){
    if(sum(x)==0){
        return(NA)
    } else {
        as.integer(names(which.max(table(x))))
    }
}
########### @JosephWood function
fasterAgg.Fun <- function(x,...) {
    myRle.Alt <- function (x1) {
        n1 <- length(x1)
        y1 <- x1[-1L] != x1[-n1]
        i <- c(which(y1), n1)
        x1[i][which.max(diff(c(0L, i)))]
    }

    if (sum(x)==0) {
        return(NA)
    } else {
        myRle.Alt(sort(x, method="quick"))
    }
}
########### Rcpp function
library(Rcpp)
library(inline)

aggrRcpp <- cxxfunction(signature(values='integer'), '
                Rcpp::IntegerVector v(clone(values));
                std::sort(v.begin(),v.end());
                int n = v.size();
                double sum = 0;
                int currentValue = 0, currentCount = 0, maxValue = 0, maxCount = 0;
                for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
                    int value = v[i];
                    sum += value;
                    if(i==0 || currentValue != value){
                      if(currentCount > maxCount){
                        maxCount = currentCount;
                        maxValue = currentValue;
                      }
                      currentValue = value;
                      currentCount = 0;
                    }else{
                      currentCount++;
                    }
                }
                if(sum == 0){
                  return Rcpp::IntegerVector::create(NA_INTEGER);
                }
                if(currentCount > maxCount){
                  maxCount = currentCount;
                  maxValue = currentValue;
                }
                return wrap( maxValue ) ;
        ', plugin="Rcpp", verbose=FALSE, 
        includes='')
# wrap it to support "..." argument
aggrRcppW <- function(x,...)aggrRcpp(x);
```

Benchmark :

```
require(raster)   
set.seed(123)
x <- matrix(rpois(10^8, 2), 10000)
a <- raster(x)

system.time(a1<-aggregate(a,fact=100,fun=agg.fun))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  35.13    0.44   35.87 
system.time(a2<-aggregate(a,fact=100,fun=fasterAgg.Fun))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   8.20    0.34    8.59
system.time(a3<-aggregate(a,fact=100,fun=aggrRcppW))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   5.77    0.39    6.22 

###########  all equal ?
all(TRUE,all.equal(a1,a2),all.equal(a2,a3))
# > [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is aggregation, wouldn't you want the `max` function?

```
library(raster)    
x <- matrix(rpois(1000000, 2),1000)
a <- aggregate(a,fact=10,fun=max)
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking for the value that occurs most frequently, not the largest.

Comment: Then you can use "fun=modal". Using system.time() and a  "raster(matrix(rpois(10^9, 2), 10000))", it took my PC 623 to process "fun=fasterAgg.Fun" from @jbaums but just 312 with "fun=modal". Still, the gdalwrap() option was by far the fastest, 147 (including the raster writing time).